# Falha ao comparar uma variavel "list" com "int" em python e SQL

Tags: mysql, python, sql, variáveis

Estou com o seguinte erro para comparar uma variavel que recebe o retorno de uma query do SQL, ela me retorna um valor que é os minutos da ultima execução de um código meu, porem eu não consigo manipular essa variavel que recebe esse tipo "list"
Codigo:

```
sql = "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE , MAX(fld_hb_datetime), NOW()) AS diferenca_minutos FROM tbl_log_heartbeat;"

mycursor.execute(sql)

result = mycursor.fetchall()

print("MINUTES SINCE LAST EXEC")
print(result)
if result < 5 :
    print("LESS THAN 5 MINUTES")
else:
    print("MORE THAN 5 MINUTES")
```

e o erro é o seguinte:

- TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int' *

alguma ideia de como manipular essa variavel? no terminal, se eu der um print nessa RESULT apenas, ela me retorna isso:

```
[(14,)]
```

Comment: O  `fetchall` deve retornar uma tupla e nao um lista. E nesse contexto acho que seria o `fetchone()`

Answer (score -1):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é acessar o índice zero da tupla.

Isso vai retornar o valor inteiro 14, e então assim você vai poder comparar o resultado no if. Segue um exemplo de implementação:

```
mycursor.execute(sql)

resultado = mycursor.fetchall()
for row in resultado:
    result = row[0]
    if result < 5 :
        print("LESS THAN 5 MINUTES")
    else:
        print("MORE THAN 5 MINUTES")
```

#### Explicando o resultado

Em mysql um cursor quando executa o fetchall retorna uma lista de tuplas, como a sua query retorna apenas uma linha com o resultado de uma coluna, então iteramos o valor e acessamos o índice zero da tupla. Assim podemos comparar o valor diretamente no comando condicional.

A grande maioria das implementações de bibliotecas de banco de dados, seguem as especificações da [PEP249](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/) então esta implementação pode ser utilizada consistentemente entre qualquer fornecedor de api para acesso ao banco de dados.

Para mais informações consulte a [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html).